# Will a balloon explode if taken to a lower height?

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science

i'm in 9th standard and we've read that a when a air-filled ballon is taken to a greater height, it explodes due to imbalance in atmospheric pressure. Does this also happen when a filled balloon is taken to a lower height ? Why?

Comment: Yes, that is why submarine doors are very hard to open in depths. Your balloon will be compressed instead of exploding.

Comment: If done slowly, I do not think the balloon will "explode."  The material may experience some issues under extreme pressures (e.g., bottom of the deepest ocean trenches) but if we ignore those issues and just consider what happens to the air inside, it should just compress as you increase the external pressure.